# way to create a 3d matrix of 2 vectors and 1 matrix

Tags: python, numpy, tensor

Hello i have a question regarding a problem I am facing in python. I was studying about tensors and I saw that each row/column of a tensor must have the same size. Is it possible to create a tensor of perhaps a 3d object or matrix where lets say we have 3 axis : x,y,z
In the x axis I want to create a vector to work as an index. So let x be from 0 to N
Then on the y axis I want to have N random integer vectors of size m (where mm
Is it possible? 
My first approach was to create a big vector of Nm and a big matrix of (N*m,N*m) dimensions where i would store all my random vectors and matrices and then if I wanted to change for example the my second vector then i would have to play with the indexes. However is there another way to approach this problem with tensors or numpy that I m unaware of?
Thank you in advance for your advices

Comment: Your question is unclear, provide few test cases/ samples so that we can understand.

Comment: I want to construct i guess a 3d matrix?(I do not know how to call it) where in 1 axis i will have a vector size N . On the y axis N vectors of size m (m<N) and on the z axis N matrices of dimensions(m,m). As a result the 1st value of my vector on the axis x will correspond as an index for the vector on axis y and the matrix on axis z.Is it possible?Or i should create a tensor just for my matrices and a tensor for my vectors and a single vector to work as index?

Answer (score 0):

First vector, N = 3, `[1,2, 3]`
Second N vectors with length m, m = 2
`[[4,5], [6,7], [7,8]]`

So, N matrices of size (m,m)
`[[[1,1], [2,2]],  [[1,1], [2,2]],  [[1,1], [2,2]] ]`

Lets create numpy arrays from them.

```
import numpy as np
N = 3
m = 2
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.random.randn(N, m)
c = np.random.randn(N, m, m)
```

You see the problem here? The last matrix c has already 3 dimensions according to your definitions.

Your argument can be simplified.

Let's say our final matrix is - 
`a = np.zeros((3,2,2))` # 3 dimensions, x,y,z
1) For first dimension -

`a[0,:,:] = 0` # first axis, first index = 0

`a[1,:,:] = 1` # first axis, 2nd index = 1

`a[2,:,:] = 2` # first axis, 3rd index = 2

2) Now, we need to fill up the rest of the positions, but dimensions don't match up.

So, it's better to create separate tensors for them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. One last question if you don t mind. Let s say i create a tensor with my N matrices [dimensions (m,m)] and a tensor with  my N vectors [dimension (m)]. And later on my program i need to use for example my 3rd matrix and 3rd vector, do some calculations and replace them with the outcome how can i do it? I mean as a syntax. Do i have to assign the 3rd matrix to a new matrix and my 3rd vector to a new vector, do the calculations and then replace them or i can do it directly? If yes, how??

Comment: If your dimension calculation is right you can definitely use numpy operations. For starter I would suggest looking into http://cs231n.github.io/python-numpy-tutorial/#numpy